# How to unistall Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, windows, uninstall, gateway

I have a Gateway laptop and I installed Ubuntu 13.10, and I want to revert back to Windows. I didn't do the dual boot option, just to let you know.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: delete the partition and install windows again..

Comment: I'm a noob, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.
How do I delete the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot ubuntu live-disk or gparted live-disk.If you boot ubuntu live-disk,you need to install **gparted**.Connect to the internet,Open up the terminal and run the below command to install gparted.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- After installation of *gparted partition Editor* completed,open it from the dash.
- Then rightclick on the partition which contains Ubuntu os and select *Fortmat To* option then format it to ntfs filesystem.So that the windows os will be installed on that partition.

[image]

- Then boot windows live-disk,and select **custom** option (*to choose in which partition does the windows os is going to be installed*) then install the windows os on the formatted ntfs partition.That's all.
- **Note:** Backup your precious datas before uninstalling ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't told Ubuntu to delete everything and use the whole drive, **try using the built in recovery** before dabbling in partition editing.